# How to automatically type text repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, text, input

I am trying to make a javascript/jquery code in which it automatically types a string, and then after the string is completely typed, clears the previously typed string and types it again. Currently, all my code does is type the string once. I know how to keep looping it, but it just starts typing where it left off, and doesn't clear the string. Javascript:

```
var txt='Typing text...'.split('');

var delay=850;

for ( i=0; i<txt.length;i++){   
setTimeout(function(){        
    $('.autoText').append(txt.shift() )
}, delay * i)       
}
```

and here is my html:

```
<h1 class="autoText" style="font-size: 50px; color: #7CFC00; margin-top: 0em; margin-left: 25%;"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q5m260fp/1/)**

```
var txt = 'Typing text...'.split('');

var delay = 850;

function type() {
    for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.autoText').append(txt.shift());
        }, delay * i);
    }

    // delay * i + 1000 means 1 second after the above text was finished typing

    setTimeout(function(){
        // after finish, clear text in h1 element
        $('.autoText').text('');

        // fire `type` method again, with `txt` reset to its original value
        type(txt = 'Typing text...'.split(''));

    }, delay * i + 1000);
}

type(); // call type at least once
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt = 'Typing text...'.split(''),
    $h1 = $('.autoText'),
    len = txt.length,
    delay = 850,
    i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    $h1.append(txt[i++]);
    if (i > len) {
        $h1.empty();
        i = 0;
    }
}, delay);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yt6hm4hc/

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var txt='Typing text...';

var delay=850;

var i = 0;

function type() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    $('.autoText').append(txt[i]);
    i++;
  } else {
    $('.autoText').text('');
    i = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(type, delay);
}

type();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16v15ufv/

Answer (score 1):

Forgive the overkill, but if you make everything really generic then you can re-use bits in other places

A function to generate each char of a string, one per invocation

```
function stringGenerator(str) {
    var i = 0;
    return function () {
        if (i < str.length)
            return str.charAt(i++);
        i = 0;
        return null;
    };
}
```

A function to loop using `setTimeout`, with a couple neat little tricks for ending the loop

```
function timeoutLoop(fn, freq, callback) {
    function looper() {
        var ret = fn();
        if (ret !== false && ret !== null && ret !== undefined)
            return window.setTimeout(looper, freq);
        if (callback)
            callback();
    }
    window.setTimeout(looper, freq)
}
```

A function which combines these with logic about text in the DOM, to produce your typing effect

```
function type(node, str, freq) {
    var s = stringGenerator(str),
        f = function () {
            var chr = s();
            if (chr === null)
                return false;
            if (node.lastChild.nodeType === 3)
                node.lastChild.data += chr;
            else
                node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chr));
            return true;
        };
    timeoutLoop(f, freq);
}
```

Finally, invocation, e.g. to have the words *Hello world!* written to the `<body>` one character every *500 ms*

```
type(document.body, 'Hello world!', 500);
```

This is 100% vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Here is the OOP solution,with Object literal way. also with method that you can change the Delay. and in the future you can add more methods like change case of string or change effects of animation with setters methods. you can append it to any element with any string.
also it's not have dependencies like a jQuery. and this code you must put in the bottom of the DOM if you don't want dependency of jQuery  or inside document ready func and with that you have dependency .
Hope it's help you.

```
    var animText =  {

        animStr: '',
        delay: 300,

        setDelay: function(delay) {
            this.delay = delay;
        },

        DoAnimation: function(string, selector) {

            this.animStr = string.split('');


            for (var i = 0; i <= string.length-1; i++) {

                setTimeout(function () {    
                    document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML += animText.animStr.shift();                 
                },this.delay * i);             
            };

            setTimeout( function() {                   
                document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = '';                
                animText.DoAnimation(string, selector);                 

            }, this.delay * i + 1200) 

        }

    }


    animText.DoAnimation("Hello", "animStr");
    animText.setDelay(900);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt='Typing text...'.split('');

var delay=850;

for ( i=0; i<txt.length;i++){   
setTimeout(function(){  
   $('.autoText').text('');
    $('.autoText').append(txt.shift() )
}, delay * i)       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion:

```
var txt='Typing text...';
var delay=850;

function TypeText($el, txt, currentIndex, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //If finished writing, restart at 0
        if (currentIndex >= txt.length) {
            TypeText($el, txt, 0, 1000);
            return;
        }

        //If at 0, empty the text
        if (currentIndex == 0) $el.empty();

        //Append current letter
        $el.append(txt[currentIndex]);

        //Append next letter
        TypeText($el, txt, currentIndex+1, timeout);
    }, timeout);
}

TypeText($('.autoText'), txt, 0, delay)
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7nuxnjcL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` within a loop you'll create your own pain in the neck.

You could use recursion, something like this:

```
function repeatEternal(str, time){
    time = time*1000 || 200;
    var position = 0
       ,rdiv = document.querySelector('#repeater')
       ,l2r = true;

    return eternal(str);

    function eternal(s){
        rdiv.textContent = l2r ? rdiv.textContent + s[0] : s.slice(0, -1);
        l2r = s.length === 1 ? !l2r : l2r;
        s = s.length < 2 ? str : !l2r ? s.slice(0,-1) : s.slice(1);
        setTimeout( function(){ eternal(s); }, time);
    }
}
// usage
repeatEternal('Typing galore!', 0.3);
```

Here's the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/qj99edem/)